# ElasticSearch nested sort with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I've documents that contain a list of prices for specific keys, for example as the following

document1

```
 {
        "name":"doc1",
        "cheapestPrices": [{
                "key": "10000_BB",
                "value": 50
            }, {
                "key": "10000_LO",
                "value": 10
            }, {
                "key": "10000",
                "value": 10
            }, {
                "key": "",
                "value": 10
            }
        ]
    }
```

document2

```
{
    "name":"doc2",
    "cheapestPrices": [{
            "key": "10000_BB",
            "value": 15
        }, {
            "key": "10000_LO",
            "value": 30
        }, {
            "key": "10000",
            "value": 15
        }, {
            "key": "",
            "value": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I send a query and I want to sort by given keys and the order should be from lowest to highest. I created this query:

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "sort": [
        {
            "cheapestPrices.value": {
                "mode": "min",
                "nested": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "cheapestPrices.key": {
                                            "value": "10000_BB"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "cheapestPrices"
                },
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Expecting that I would get doc2 (value 15 for that key) first and then doc1 (value 50 for that key)... but the result are doc1 and then doc2 and the sort score is exactly the same.

Result:

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "test_sortbyprice",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "doc1",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "cheapestPrices": [{
                            "key": "10000_BB",
                            "value": 50
                        }, {
                            "key": "10000_LO",
                            "value": 10
                        }, {
                            "key": "10000",
                            "value": 10
                        }, {
                            "key": "",
                            "value": 10
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "doc1"
                },
                "sort": [
                    9223372036854775807
                ]
            }, {
                "_index": "test_sortbyprice",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "doc2",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "cheapestPrices": [{
                            "key": "10000_BB",
                            "value": 15
                        }, {
                            "key": "10000_LO",
                            "value": 30
                        }, {
                            "key": "10000",
                            "value": 15
                        }, {
                            "key": "",
                            "value": 15
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "doc2"
                },
                "sort": [
                    9223372036854775807
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The mapping is as follow:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "cheapestPrices": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "key": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "ignore_above": 256,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

Change the `term` query to target the field `cheapestPrices.key.keyword` instead of `cheapestPrices.key`.

---

The sort query does not match any documents due to using `term` (an exact match) on a field that's been lowercased thanks to the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which was applied by default on a `text` field w/ no extra analyzers. This means it's never going to equal `10000_BB` (uppercase). But luckily you have the `.keyword` available which ensures no value modifications.

The sort scores are the same (I assume `9223372036854775807` a.k.a. `Long.MAX_VALUE`) because that's the default ES behavior. It's not really that far fetched when you think about it: if the sort query does not match anything, it'll assign the highest possible value.

If your `order` were `desc`, it'd have returned `-Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: yes, that did the trick. I found out just before you answered, but thank you anyway.